# VBA 1004 Application defined or Object defned error

Tags: vba, excel

While running this code, I am getting

> VBA 1004 error: "Application defined or Object defined error"

on the line indicated below. Why?

I am using *Excel 2013*. My spreadsheet has 2 sheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2.

```
Public Sub ImportTextFile()

Dim RowNdx As Long
Dim TempVal As String
Dim WholeLine As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'On Error GoTo EndMacro:
RowNdx = 11
FName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value

Open FName For Input Access Read As #1

While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, WholeLine
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNdx, 1).Value = WholeLine ' <~~~~~~ ERROR
    RowNdx = RowNdx + 1
Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: Not enough info to reproduce problem. Try stepping through your code in debug mode and watching how your variables evolve ([instructions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)). What's the value of `RowNdx` and `WholeLine` when the error happens?

Comment: RowNdx = 11 when the error occurs. I am reading from a simple text file (containing 450 rows). So Wholeline at the time of error contains "ABCxyz". 
Again this code is a simple code to read from a text file and copy its whole contents to the excel spreadsheet from Row 11 onwards.

I also tried to step thru the code. In the While loop, I tried to comment the Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNdx, 1).Value = WholeLine during the first run through the loop. During the second iteration of the loop, I uncommented this line. It then ran through fine till the end.

Comment: I wonder if there's something in `WholeLine` that Excel doesn't like. Something like a Chr(13) without Chr(10) although that's not it. Can you loop through each letter of WholeLine on the line that causes the error and `Debug.Print Mid$(WholeLine,i,1), Asc(Mid$(WholeLine,i,1))` where `i` is your control variable? It might be useful to see what kind of characters are in there.

Comment: Yes. @DickKusLeika, you are right. My file had the following line. It was causing me the error.
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2015.04.10 14:12:25 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=

I removed that line from the text file and the code worked fine. Seems like Excel didnt like the '=' as the first character in the text file.

Is there a way to copy all the lines from the text file, no matter what it contains? 

Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I had spend quite a few hours changing my code without success.

Answer (score 1):

If the first character of your line is an equal sign, Excel will think you're entering a formula. And the line in your comment that starts with an equal sign is not a valid formula - no surprise there! Excel complains because you're trying to enter a formula that's not valid.

You can prefix an apostrophe

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNdx, 1).Value = "'" & WholeLine
```

That will treat every line like text - it won't convert date strings to dates are numerics to actual numbers and leaves everything just as it is. It's probably a better option that checking for an equal sign explicitly because then you also have to check for a plus sign, minus sign, etc. So keep everything as a string with the leading apostrophe unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Dick. Your help is much appreciated.